# where i can get software download for ubuntu 9?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper step-by-setp procedure to install any application in ubuntu ?](https://superuser.com/questions/100006/what-is-the-proper-step-by-setp-procedure-to-install-any-application-in-ubuntu)

i want a web site where i can download softwares or application for ubuntu 9

Answer (score 7):

Software installation in Ubuntu is very different from Windows. See this help page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/add-applications/C/installation-windows-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

There are other questions on this subject, for instance check out [this one.](https://superuser.com/questions/100006/what-is-the-proper-step-by-setp-procedure-to-install-any-application-in-ubuntu/)