# can linux (software, application and drivers ) work on ubuntu 9?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where i can get software download for ubuntu 9 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/101813/where-i-can-get-software-download-for-ubuntu-9)

i cant find much (softwares, applications and derivers).can linux (software, application and drivers ) work on ubuntu 9?

Comment: you may want to rephrase your question, i.e. what type of software are you looking for? which hardware are you using that you need drivers for?

Comment: Dupe - http://superuser.com/questions/101813/where-i-can-get-software-download-for-ubuntu-9

Comment: i want ubunto drivers of nvidia geforce FX5200....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if Linux software works on Ubuntu, the answer is yes, as Ubuntu is a "flavor" or "distribution" of Linux.  Linux generally refers to just the operating system kernel, the core of the OS.  That + the libraries and tools is referred to as GNU/Linux, and Ubuntu is that + a set of programs pre-packaged to work well together, which is called a Linux Distribution.

Ubuntu is Linux:)

Comment: A Gentoo user could kill you for the above analogy (Ubuntu=Linux): do you know that? :D

Comment: Hahaha:)  I suppose I should have clarified "For the Purposes of the Discussion at Hand"!

Answer (score 2):

- For Software, get familiar with the synaptics software tool and/or apt-get or aptitude. As well look into freshmeat.com.
- For drivers, your best if Ubuntu can't figure it out, is to check ubuntuforums.com and/or go on irssi server irc.freenode.net and room #ubuntu

Through normal applications, wine, codeweavers, I have both my windows, linux apps working flawlessly.